# ElasticSearch Query DSL Combine Terms and Wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I have to distinct queries which are working well enough alone:

`{"wildcard":{"city":"*Beach*"}}
{"terms":{"state":["Florida","Georgia"]}}`

but trying to combine them into one query is proving to be quite the challenge.

I had thought just doing simply `{{"wildcard":{"city":"*Beach*"}},{"terms":{"state":["Florida","Georgia"]}}}` would do it, but it does not. So then I tried a few different iterations using arrays, and bool queries etc. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html) should be the right way to go.

Below is an example for your use case:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": { "city": "*Beach*" }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "state": [ "Florida", "Georgia" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If there is not result, it means that there is no entry matching both of the criteria.

Comment: Ah, this is working. Is there any reason why just combing two working hashes into a bigger hash wasn't made to work?

Comment: Great to hear that it's working. Your syntax does not work just because it's not the valid DSL supported by Elasticsearch.